# Мультиязычность через модуль ActiveQuery

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте, проблема в том что пытаюсь сделать чтобы через

```
Pages::find()->all();
```

выводились две базы, общая и язык.
Почему-то не срабатывает правильно:

```
public function all($db = null)
{
    $this->select(['pages.*', '`pages_lang`.title']);
    $this->leftJoin('pages_lang', 'pages.id = pages_lang.page_id AND pages_lang.lang_id = '.Lang::getCurrent()['id']);
    return parent::all($db);
}
```

Выводятся только данные из pages....

Answer (score 2):

Лучше описать взаимосвязь у модели Pages к модели к примеру Languages

```
public function Language()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Languages::className(), ['id' => 'lang_id']);
    //      если предполагается связь один ко многим, то используем hasMany
    //      return $this->hasMany(Languages::className(), ['id' => 'lang_id']);
}
```

а потом просто обращаться к модели Languages как к свойству Pages

```
$page = Pages::findOne(1);
var_dump($page->language->attributes);
```